# Magento2 : gtmetrix website prerformnce

Tags: magento2, performance, nginx, websites

I have checked my website in getmetrix tool,it is ngnix server.Site Page speed score is F(0%) showing

It shows

```
     Defer parsing of JavaScript - E(57)
     Leverage browser caching - F(0)
```

I studied but unable to get any solution. How to fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034465/how-to-add-leverage-browser-caching-for-cdn-in-htaccess Combination of 2 questions

Comment: but this is for apache, my site is nginx @Ankith

Comment: Do you have js bundling enabled?

Comment: in magneto having option of js bundling but i didnt enabled

Comment: Please refer this extension, It helps you optimize your Magento website and Increases the Speed score.

https://marketplace.magento.com/bitware-speedenginedeferjs.html